# Prevent array overwriting and instead create new array index

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a file and I need the save the content of the file in my MySQL database. Here is the code that I am using to parse the file:

```
$lines = file($tmp_filename);
$data = array();
if (($handle = fopen($tmp_filename, 'r')) !== FALSE)
{
  while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";", "\"", "\n")) !== FALSE)
    {
      $key = array_shift($row);
      $data[$key] = $row;
    }
  fclose($handle);
}
```

and here are the contents of the file that I am parsing:

```
HDR;Payroll Interface;5496;2012-07-20
NM1;082;IN2;12345678;2001-01-15;Mr;Marcial;Gustav;Gustav,Marcial;PRI;Marcial
PR1;082;IN2;12345678;7 The School;Alvarez;Bahaghari; ;Gandum
PR2;082;IN2;12345678;400006;IND;M;M;2007-10-16;1976-03-31
PR3;082;IN2;12345678; ; ;A;
**truncated**
```

[Click Here for full data](http://pastebin.com/3DKk4V5A)

There are scenarios where the array has the same index and the same value but I still need to save these data but array overwriting occurs. What must be added to put the same array to a different array index?

[Take a look at this and tell me what i am missing](http://pastebin.com/P6gWDt6n)

Comment: If you're worried about `$row` being lost because there could be two `$key`s, then why not just keep an internal counter instead of using `$key` as your index? Ex. `$data[$count++] = $row;` where `$count = 0;`.

Comment: @DaveChen i edited my post and please see the link and the bottom of my question. thanks :)

Comment: So duplicates will be placed in another array?

Comment: Yeah... the duplicates should be put in another array so that i can save them both

Comment: Why don't you just change the way you are saving them? You can always put NM1 in the array itself, so you can use regular numbers as your index. I assume you are using something like `foreach ($array1 as $index => $el)` to save, and that's why you want to keep the index. The issue is that you'll need to process more arrays for duplicates.

Comment: i dont think changing the way to save the items will solved this.  Because data will be saved to different tables and i think it will be great it i can pull all the data related to a person to a single array. Its like 1 person per array.

Comment: Do you mean 1 person per element within an array? For conclusiveness please post how you are saving your data in the database. There's essentially two facts: 1) You can't have two array elements with the same index, 2) It's not efficient to process more than one array, you should have that in one self-containing array.

Comment: Yeah 1 person per element. And it is not possible to have to array elements with same index that's why i want to put in new element the duplicate array

Comment: It's not efficient to process more than one array. I'm guessing that you are saving an array with a foreach, and that's why you want to keep the index. Please post how you are saving the data.

Answer (score 2):

The data in the array is being overwritten because you are reassigning the value of `$key` each time it is encountered.

What you want to do is create a secondary array as the `$key` value and push nodes into that array this way you end up with your expected result.

```
[
    'NM1' => ['...', '...'],
    'PR1' => ['...', '...']
]
```

The code would be,

```
while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";", "\"", "\n")) !== FALSE) {
    $key = array_shift($row);
    // Notice the extra []
    $data[$key][] = $row;
}
```

Each key will now contain an array with a node for each row encountered.

Comment: At my work were stuck on 5.3 tell our server host can update MySql, something to do with the way PDO handles database password encryption, but I have 5.4 locally, just for reference it would be  = array() in 5.3, closures and $this get me on 5.3 to if you know what I mean.

Comment: `if (!isset($data[$key])) $data[$key] = [];` on the other hand it gives mu this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['`

Comment: Are you using less than PHP 5.4? As @ArtisiticPhoenix pointed out the ```$data[$key] = []``` should be ```$data[$key] = array();``` for less than 5.4 users. I've updated my answer so it is compatible with PHP <= 5.4

Answer (score 1):

try changing:

```
...
$data[$key] = $row;
```

to

```
...
$data[][$key] = $row;
```

Comment: thanks for answering this question. See the link on the bottom part of my question. Illustrated there what should be the look of desired output.